# How to i find html file in my project directory on browser inspect ?

Tags: html, find, inspect

on inspect, I find CSS property easily where the CSS file is located. but I want to find the HTML file on inspecting the browser where the HTML file is located.

> such, when I inspect the browser and where put the cursor an element
>   or tag indicates. now I find that in which HTML file contains the
>   element or tag.

please, nobody answer about CSS file located.

Comment: The 'html file' is the lines of html code that you check your css with in browser inspect.

Comment: No. your answer is not right. it seems to me you didn't understand. on inspect we find on hover a tag such as img or div element. my question is in which file contains the tag or element.